# Magnet Link with .NET and WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, magnet-uri

I'm just looking for a sample project to get an idea for how I should implement my application.

Just like in torrent files, I want to open and fire an event in a WPF application via a Website link. How do I do this ?

Comment: Interesting question... I know there's MonoTorrent, but I don't know if it would give you the amount of freedom you're looking for.  You could, of course, look at their source code and see how they did it: https://github.com/mono/monotorrent  I should warn you, though... that the question is completely off-topic, due to how you're asking it (3rd party library).  I would reword it before it gets closed down.

Comment: I'm removing it and I could manage to solve my problem. I'll post the answer tomorrow in case others might need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Here is how I solved it.

1. I'm adding the registry key to register custom URL Scheme first

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\KA] @="URL:KA Protocol" "URL Protocol"=""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\KA\shell]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\KA\shell\open]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\KA\shell\open\command]
>   @="\"C:\Users\me\Desktop\myapp\myapp.exe\" \"%1\""

2. Typing KA://myargument in Internet Explorer to try to process myapp.exe
3. Handling in my WPF app as this in App.cs

   > ```
   > public partial class App : Application
   > {
   >     void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   >     {
   >         for (int i = 0; i != e.Args.Length; ++i)
   >         {
   >             if (e.Args[i].StartsWith("ka:"))
   >             {
   >                 int index = e.Args[i].IndexOf(':') +1;
   >                 string argg= e.Args[i].Substring(index, e.Args[i].Length - index); // handling argument here
   >
   >             }
   >         }
   >
   >         Shell mainWindow = new Container();
   >         mainWindow.Show();
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

Answer (score 1):

I would check out this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and create a custom URL scheme of yourApp://WHatInfoYouNeed